# C++ size_t or ptrdiff_t

Tags: c++

If you have the following code where p is a pointer:

```
p = p + strlen(p) + size_t(1);
```

Since `strlen()` and `size_t` are both `size_t`, should I cast the code to `ptrdiff_t` ?

```
p = p + (ptrdiff_t)(strlen(p) + size_t(1));
```

If so why?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: what you are trying to do is invalid C++ because the `p + (ptrdiff_t)(strlen(p) + size_t(1))` address is out of the array of char pointed by `p`.

Comment: not necessarily.  the p array does not need to END at the null.

Comment: @JB Jansen: You cannot know that in general - it depends how the memory for `p` was allocated. There is nothing in C that would stop a string to be shorter (!) than the memory block hosting it.

Comment: @JB, Alex, FrankH: In any case, it is well-defined and normal to construct a pointer to the memory location one-past-the-end.  That's what `std::vector::end()` does for example.  You can't dereference that pointer, but it IS explicitly valid for all other pointer operations.  Relevant quote from the standard: <quote>Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, **or one past the last element of the array object**, the behavior is undefined.</quote>

Comment: It should also be noted that you really don't need the size_t cast here. The compiler will probably complain about "signed/unsigned mismatch", in which case the correct fix is to write `1u` or `1ul` instead of the cast.

Comment: If I had that C++ code, I would instantly refactor it to use a string class.

Comment: @DeadMG: wow, you're a fast typist. Instant is pretty good for any refactor.

Comment: @Steve: I do bend the laws of physics from time to time. I meant instantly decide to refactor, not instantly refactor literally.

Comment: @DeadMG: sorry, just kidding. "I would refactor as soon as I'd had a coffee", maybe.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[std::ptrdiff_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) is signed. [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is unsigned. Casting `strlen(p)` to `ptrdiff_t` would make sense if `p` could have a negative length, which is not possible.

However, that cast could overflow the resulting signed value if `p` is large enough (for instance, larger than 2,147,483,647 bytes on most 32-bit platforms). So it could introduce an error in your pointer arithmetic.

Best to stick with `size_t` here.

Comment: ptrdiff_t seems broken, anyway, since 2G isn't enough to represent the difference in pointers to the first and last elements of a 3G array. If you use the ptrdiff_t data type in any way, your program has a bug. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t

Comment: @VaddadiKartick on 64 bit systems `PTRDIFF_MAX` is equal to `9223372036854775807` which looks enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to cast to `ptrdiff_t`.  Pointer arithmetic is well-defined for all integral types, including `size_t`, and if `size_t` wasn't big enough to hold the value, the cast to `ptrdiff_t` comes too late anyway.

Here is the relevant language from the Standard (C++0x FCD, section `[expr.add]`):

> When an expression that has integral
>   type is added to or subtracted from a
>   pointer, the result has the type of
>   the pointer operand.  If the pointer
>   operand points to an element of an
>   array object, and the array is large
>   enough, the result points to an
>   element offset from the original
>   element such that the difference of
>   the subscripts of the resulting and
>   original array elements equals the
>   integral expression. In other words,
>   if the expression P points to the i
>   -th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently,
>   N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the
>   value n ) point to, respectively, the
>   i + n -th and i − n -th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist.
>   Moreover, if the expression P points
>   to the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (P)+1 points
>   one past the last element of the array
>   object, and if the expression Q points
>   one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to
>   the last element of the array object. 
>   If both the pointer operand and the
>   result point to elements of the same
>   array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the
>   evaluation shall not produce an
>   overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.